# Why Degree and Radian gives different answer for $\sin(\pi^2)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trigonometry

I tried to solve $\sin(\pi^2)$ in degrees and radians but I am getting different answer for both of them.

For Degrees: $\sin(180^2) = 0$

For Radians: $\sin(3.14^2) = -0.43$

Why I am getting different answer for both of them?
What is the correct way to solve it.

Comment: please change your calculator settings from degree to radian

Comment: Why would you expect to get the same result?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This has nothing to do with calculator settings, he is using the correct settings.

Comment: If he was using degree settings to calculate sin(3.14^2) he would not have got a negative value.

Comment: You need to take into account dimension. (10 cm)$^2\neq$100 cm, and $\pi^2=(180^\circ)^2\neq 32400^\circ$. But when you use calculator in degree mode it considers $\sin(180^2)$ as $\sin((180^2)^\circ)=\sin(32400^\circ)$.

Comment: And there is something wrong in calculation sine of squared angles.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu It's possible that someone needs to calculate $\sin x^2$ for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: I suppose $x^2$ is phase difference in diffraction, phase difference can be considered as angle, not squared angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've entered doesn't have any meaning, because what you've written as $\sin ((180^\circ)^2)$ in degrees is the same thing as $\sin (180\pi)$ in radians, not $\sin(\pi^2)$. You can't discuss $\sin (x^2)$ using degrees, you always have to convert to radians.

It might help if you actually think of the $^\circ$ as meaning "$\pi\over 180$". $(180^\circ)^2$ is already a nonsense.

Comment: So can we assume that all the trigonometric functions(sin, cos, tan..) are meant to be done in radians? We are using degrees just because it is easy to imagine for us?

Comment: @AamodThakur yes, it's much more natural to use radians. This should be covered in calculus courses/books etc.

Comment: @Aamod Thakur: There are trigonometric functions of angles and trigonometric functions of real (or complex) argument. There is accordance in these notions such that trigonometric function of angle $x$ radians has the same value as corresponding trigonometric function (having the same name) of real argument $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If you regard $\,^\circ$ as meaning "multiply by $\frac{2\pi}{360}$", so $180^\circ=\pi$,

then $(180^\circ)^2 \not = (180^2)^\circ$, and that is what is causing your issue.

In particular $\sin\left((180^\circ)^2\right) = \sin\left(\pi^2\right) \not= 0$ while $\sin\left((180^2)^\circ\right)= \sin\left(32400^\circ\right)= \sin\left(180 \pi\right)=0$